# Does this statement on symmetric matrix hold?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $K$ be a symmetric matrix of dimension $n*n$. Is the following statement true:

For any vector $C$ and $D$ of dimension $n*1$, $C^T K D = D^T K C$

The above holds when I tried with simple matrices. But I do not know if it holds in general and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equal.

$$(C^T K D)^T = D^T K^T C = D^T K C$$

Since the left-hand side is a scalar (as is the right-hand side), it equals its transpose.

Comment: Thanks. Very cool proof!

Comment: You are welcome!